# Proving that there is no continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ satisfying $f(\Bbb Q)\subset\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$ and $f(\Bbb R-\Bbb Q) \subset\Bbb Q$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

How can I prove that there is no continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(\mathbb{Q}) \subset \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q} ) \subset \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: The answers to this question are an impenetrable mess because the first version was flawed. You can't tell which version of the question is being answered! How can we fix this??

Comment: Sorry, man. =/ Arpit Kansal answered me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $\bf R$ is connected and $f$ is non constant hence$f(\bf R)$ is  connected and hence uncountable.

Comment: I changed the question. Because Q is countable and R-Q is not, the other question was obvious. Your hint works for this case?

Comment: Note that because $Q$ is countable hence $f(Q)$ is countable,also $f(R\Q)$ is countable because contained in $Q$.Hence $f(R)$ is countable,contradiction!

Comment: what's the problem with $f(R)$ be countable?

Comment: @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior Do you know only connected set in $R$ are intervals?

Comment: oh, yes. Sorry, man. Since f is continuous and non constant, f(R) is connected, and so uncountable. You made it!

Comment: Correction: You made it! Thanks.

Comment: Dear @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior,You're welcome!

Answer (score 8):

Hint: $f(\Bbb Q)$ is countable.

New hint given the edit: 
$f(\Bbb R)$ must be connected, and hence an interval, and hence must contain uncountably many irrationals.

Comment: Sorry, I saw this problem. So I changed the question. See it again.

Comment: @FernandoVieiraCostaJúnior: The hint is still good. Note that $[a,b]\setminus \mathbb Q$ is _not_ countable.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Use the fact that

> Between any two rational numbers, we have infinite irrational numbers

and similarly,

> Between any two irrational numbers, we have infinite rational numbers.